# How to add music to an image with mencoder

Tags: mencoder

I'm trying to use mencoder to make a video that has music playing over a single image. I'm using mf to add the image and I always get a video with about one second of audio with a reported length of 0:00. I've tried with a variety of mp3's and images from different sources and I tried using various codecs and options but I can't seem to get past this problem. Here's the basic command:

`mencoder "mf://image.jpg" -o out.avi -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mjpeg -audiofile music.mp3 -oac copy`

Does anyone know how to do this or why mencoder cuts the music to one second?

Answer (score 3):

It's because the default FPS is set to 30, so mencoder expects 30 images per second -- you have to tell mencoder to use one image for whole record, so you have to set FPS to 1/"duration".

Add this options:

```
-fps 1/132.8 -ofps 30
```

where `132.8` is duration (in seconds) of your audio.

So result should look like this:

```
mencoder mf://image.jpg -o out.avi \
        -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mjpeg -audiofile music.mp3 \
        -oac copy -fps 1/132.8 -ofps 30
```

Comment: That did the trick. Encoding size wasn't an issue - I can get a file that is basically the size of the mp3 and jpg together.

Comment: Just one problem - I can't seek through the video. I thought -idx would work but it didn't help - even when running a second pass just with idx and a/v copy. I also tried -forceidx and setting keyint in avcopts. Is it not possible when there's no scene changes?

Comment: You can just put 1/100000 and this will work too. (Thanks btw)

Answer (score 1):

I only have came with an alternative where you would provide the same image from a pipe:

```
for x in `seq 1 55`; do cat image.jpg; done | mencoder -o out.avi -fps 1 -ovc lavc -demuxer lavf -lavfdopts format=mjpeg -audiofile music.mp3 -oac copy -
```

where you would replace 55 with the number of seconds you wish (this would be the length of the song, as you wish).

But, as you can see, it's **dumber** than the simple and straight-to-the-point answer by Vojtech. Only advantage I got with this alternative of mine was a smaller resulting file size.